# Is there a way to pass a dynamic GraphQL query to a graphql() decorated Component when using Apollo Client 2.0?

Tags: reactjs, apollo, react-apollo

I encounter this issue sometimes when I am working with dynamic data. It's an issue with higher-order components which are mounted before the data they need is available.

I am looking to decorate a component with the `graphql()` HOC in Apollo Client, like this:

```
export default compose(
  connect(),
  graphql(QUERY_NAME),  <-- I want QUERY_NAME to be determined at run-time
)(List)
```

The problem is I don't know **how to get Apollo to use a query that is determined by the wrapped component at run-time**.

I have a file that exports queries based on type:

```
import listFoo from './foo'
import listBar from './bar'
import listBaz from './baz'

export default {
  foo,
  bar,
  baz,
}
```

I can access them by `listQueries[type]`, but `type` is only known inside the component, and it is available as `this.props.fromRouter.type`.

Is there a strategy I can use to achieve:

```
export default compose(
  connect(),
  graphql(listQueries[type]),
)(List)
```

I think there might be a way to do it like this:

```
export default compose(
  connect(),
  graphql((props) => ({
    query: listQueries[props.fromRouter.type],
  })),
)(List)
```

Am I on the right track?

Another possible solution could be to make the Component generate its own sub-component that is wrapped with `graphql()` because the query would be known then.

For example:

```
const tableWithQuery = graphql(listQueries[props.fromRouter.type])((props) => {
  return <Table list={props.data} />
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out.

1. I have a Router Component that reads `this.props.match.params` to get the **type** of view and requested **action**.
2. With this information, I can create just one List, Create, Edit, and View Component and supply each with whatever queries are needed.
3. I created a function that gets all queries and mutations for a supplied **type**.
4. It was actually quite simple to just take the component such as `<List />` and wrap it with `graphql()` and give it the correct query or mutation that was just determined.
5. Now, the components mount with `this.props.data` being populated with the correct data
6. I spread in all the queries and mutations just in case I need them. I suspect I will need them when I go to read `this.props.data[listQueryName]`. (which will grab the data in, for example, `this.props.data.getAllPeople`)

Here is the logic (I will include all of it, to minimize confusion of future searchers):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { compose, graphql, withApollo } from 'react-apollo'
import listQueries from './list/queries'
import createMutations from './forms/create/mutations'
import editMutations from './forms/edit/mutations'
import viewQueries from './forms/view/queries'
import List from './list/List'
import Create from './forms/create/Create'
import Edit from './forms/edit/Edit'
import View from './forms/view/View'
// import Delete from './delete/Delete'

class Router extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      serverErrors: [],
    }
  }

  getGraphQL = (type) => {
    console.log('LIST QUERY', listQueries[type])
    console.log('LIST QUERY NAME', listQueries[type].definitions[0].name.value)
    console.log('CREATE MUTATION', createMutations[type])
    console.log('CREATE MUTATION NAME', createMutations[type].definitions[0].name.value)
    console.log('EDIT MUTATION', editMutations[type])
    console.log('EDIT MUTATION NAME', editMutations[type].definitions[0].name.value)
    console.log('VIEW QUERY', viewQueries[type])
    console.log('VIEW QUERY NAME', viewQueries[type].definitions[0].name.value)
    return {
      listQuery: listQueries[type],
      listQueryName: listQueries[type].definitions[0].name.value,
      createMutation: createMutations[type],
      createMutationName: createMutations[type].definitions[0].name.value,
      editMutation: editMutations[type],
      editMutationName: editMutations[type].definitions[0].name.value,
      viewQuery: viewQueries[type],
      viewQueryName: viewQueries[type].definitions[0].name.value,
    }
  }

  renderComponentForAction = (params) => {
    const { type, action } = params
    const GQL = this.getGraphQL(type)
    const {
      listQuery, createMutation, editMutation, viewQuery,
    } = GQL

    // ADD QUERIES BASED ON URL
    const ListWithGraphQL = graphql(listQuery)(List)
    const CreateWithGraphQL = graphql(createMutation)(Create)
    const EditWithGraphQL = compose(
      graphql(viewQuery),
      graphql(editMutation),
    )(Edit)
    const ViewWithGraphQL = graphql(viewQuery)(View)
    if (!action) {
      console.log('DEBUG: No action in URL, defaulting to ListView.')
      return <ListWithGraphQL fromRouter={params} {...GQL} />
    }
    const componentFor = {
      list: <ListWithGraphQL fromRouter={params} {...GQL} />,
      create: <CreateWithGraphQL fromRouter={params} {...GQL} />,
      edit: <EditWithGraphQL fromRouter={params} {...GQL} />,
      view: <ViewWithGraphQL fromRouter={params} {...GQL} />,
      // delete: <Delete fromRouter={params} {...GQL} />,
    }
    if (!componentFor[action]) {
      console.log('DEBUG: No component found, defaulting to ListView.')
      return <ListWithGraphQL fromRouter={params} {...GQL} />
    }
    return componentFor[action]
  }
  render() {
    return this.renderComponentForAction(this.props.match.params)
  }
}

Router.propTypes = {
  match: PropTypes.shape({
    params: PropTypes.shape({ type: PropTypes.string }),
  }).isRequired,
}

export default compose(connect())(withApollo(Router))
```

If this code becomes useful for someone later. I recommend commenting everything out except code necessary to render the List View. Start with verifying the props are coming in to a little "hello world" view. Then, you will be done the hard part once you get correct data in there.

Comment: You're creating a lot of expensive objects in your render method here, I'm not sure this is an ideal approach. I think you were on the right track suggesting graphql() could take a function as its first argument that derived the query from props, but sadly I don't think the library supports that yet.